# Upload data from stdin as a file with a specific name via cURL

Tags: curl, file-upload, stdin

I'm using `curl -F file=@- http://etc/upload` to upload some data I'm piping into cURL, and that's working fine, but I'd like to be able to specify the file name that's reported to the server.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the cURL man page:

> -F/--form <name=content>
>
> ...
>
> You can [...] explicitly change the name field of an file upload part by setting filename=, like this:
>
> **curl** -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost"

So this is exactly what I wanted. E.g.:

```bash
echo funfunfun | curl -F file=@-;filename=fun.txt http://etc/upload
```

I swear I had read the man pages a couple times before asking, but hadn't found that particular paragraph until now.

Comment: funny how that stuff hides

Answer (score 6):

For protocols other than HTTP, and to use `PUT` for HTTP rather than form submission, use `-T -` with filename in URL:

```sh
echo bla-bla-bla | curl -T - ftp://user:password@example.com/foo.txt
```